# How to create multiple word documents from rows using excel vba?

Tags: excel, vba

I've got an excel worksheet that has multiple individuals' info. I need to populate a word template for each individual. All the names are listed in `Column A` with each subset of information in `Columns B:N`. I have a template pre-made that has certain text values that I'm replacing with data from specific columns. My code works perfect currently for individual rows. I need it to loop so that I can get all the documents created and filled in with one click. I also need some help writing a portion of code that based off a value of 0,1,2,or 3 in the "<>" cell, a line of text will be inserted. I tried to write a formula in excel using the `IF` formula, but the text line I needed to input was too long. Any help at all would be GREATLY appreciated.

My code is as follows...

```
Sub ReplaceText()
Dim wApp As Word.Application
Dim wDoc As Word.Document
Set wApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
wApp.Visible = True

Set wDoc = wApp.Documents.Open("z:\Sound Sleepers\forms\PCP.dotx")

With wDoc
    .Application.Selection.Find.Text = "<<PCP>>"
    .Application.Selection.Find.Execute
    .Application.Selection = Range("D2")
    .Application.Selection.EndOf
    
    .Application.Selection.Find.Text = "<<name>>"
    .Application.Selection.Find.Execute
    .Application.Selection = Range("A2")
    .Application.Selection.EndOf
    
    .Application.Selection.Find.Text = "<<dob>>"
    .Application.Selection.Find.Execute
    .Application.Selection = Range("B2")
    .Application.Selection.EndOf
    
    .Application.Selection.Find.Text = "<<dos>>"
    .Application.Selection.Find.Execute
    .Application.Selection = Range("M2")
    .Application.Selection.EndOf
    
    .Application.Selection.Find.Text = "<<results>>"
    .Application.Selection.Find.Execute
    .Application.Selection = Range("O2")
    .Application.Selection.EndOf
    
    .Application.Selection.Find.Text = "<<Sleep>>"
    .Application.Selection.Find.Execute
    .Application.Selection = Range("L2")
    .Application.Selection.EndOf
    
    .Application.Selection.Find.Text = "<<Sleep>>"
    .Application.Selection.Find.Execute
    .Application.Selection = Range("L2")
    .Application.Selection.EndOf
    

    .SaveAs2 Filename:=("Oneida PCP"), _
    FileFormat:=wdFormatXMLDocument, AddtoRecentFiles:=False
End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the `for` loop. It saves the document using the value from column A.

```
Sub ReplaceText()
    Dim wApp As Word.Application
    Dim wDoc As Word.Document
    Set wApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    wApp.Visible = True
    
    
    lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row ' all of column A
    For r = 2 To lastRow  ' each row
        DocName = Range("A" & r).Value
    
        Set wDoc = wApp.Documents.Open("z:\Sound Sleepers\forms\PCP.dotx")
        With wDoc
            .Application.Selection.Find.Text = "<<PCP>>"
            .Application.Selection.Find.Execute
            .Application.Selection = Range("D" & r)
            .Application.Selection.EndOf
            
            .Application.Selection.Find.Text = "<<name>>"
            .Application.Selection.Find.Execute
            .Application.Selection = Range("A" & r)
            .Application.Selection.EndOf
            
            .Application.Selection.Find.Text = "<<dob>>"
            .Application.Selection.Find.Execute
            .Application.Selection = Range("B" & r)
            .Application.Selection.EndOf
            
            .Application.Selection.Find.Text = "<<dos>>"
            .Application.Selection.Find.Execute
            .Application.Selection = Range("M" & r)
            .Application.Selection.EndOf
            
            .Application.Selection.Find.Text = "<<results>>"
            .Application.Selection.Find.Execute
            .Application.Selection = Range("O" & r)
            .Application.Selection.EndOf
            
            .Application.Selection.Find.Text = "<<Sleep>>"
            .Application.Selection.Find.Execute
            .Application.Selection = Range("L" & r)
            .Application.Selection.EndOf
            
            .Application.Selection.Find.Text = "<<Sleep>>"
            .Application.Selection.Find.Execute
            .Application.Selection = Range("L" & r)
            .Application.Selection.EndOf
            
            NormalCheck = Range("O" & r).Value
            Phrase = "Invalid Normal Check"
            Select Case NormalCheck 
              Case 0 
                Phrase = "Normal"
              Case 1 
                Phrase = "Abnormal Questionnaire, Normal ESS" 
              Case 2 
                Phrase = "Normal Questionnaire, Abnormal ESS" 
              Case 3 
                Phrase = "Abnormal Questionnaire, Abnormal ESS" 
              Case Else 
                Phrase = "Invalid Normal Check" 
            End Select 
            
            .Application.Selection.Find.Text = "<<NormalCheck>>"
            .Application.Selection.Find.Execute
            .Application.Selection = Phrase
            .Application.Selection.EndOf
               
            .SaveAs2 Filename:=(DocName), _
            FileFormat:=wdFormatXMLDocument, AddtoRecentFiles:=False
        End With
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: I'm getting a "Compile error: Next without For" dialogue box that pops up when attempting to debug... any help? Thanks for your help by the way.

Comment: Just got it sorted. I just needed to move the "next" below the "end with" statement.

Comment: concerning the 0-3 lookup, For each individual there is a value assigned in column "O". If they have a 0, I would need it to say a long phrase about being normal. If the value is a "1" it would need to say a long phrase about having an abnormal questionnaire, but a normal ESS. If the value was a 2, it would need to say a phrase about a normal questionnaire, but an abnormal ESS. And lastly if the value were a 3 I would need to say a phrase about an abnormal ESS and abnormal Questionnaire.

Comment: The phrase should be added to the word document?

Comment: Answer updated with Normal check. Apologies for previous typo.